# ACL retrieve alias in AROS table?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

So I finally got "ACL" to work, and now im trying to get the "alias" value from the "AROS" table.
I want to make a simple message like logged in as .... (admin, moderator or user).

After some tinkering i got the "alias" value from the code below but I can't shed the feeling ther's an easier way to do this. Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Currently im using:

```
    $logindata = $this->Acl->Aro->findByForeignKey($user['User']['id']);
    $parent_id = $logindata['Aro']['parent_id'];
    $rankdata = $this->Acl->Aro->find('first', array('recursive' => -1, 'conditions' => array('Aro.id' => $parent_id)));
    $rank = $rankdata['Aro']['alias'];
```

Comment: Johan Koele, zwoele man.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option for you which is simpler than yours..i tried that in my project.

1.Save your aros with the same alias as its parent.And then you can use it simply with one line code.

2.Or you can save its parent alias into users table and then you get this all again almost every part of your site with $auth .

Comment: Im not really a fan of having the same data in multiple locations but i think this is one of those exceptions, thanks for the answer.